# cellForRowAtIndexPath not called after filter

Tags: ios, swift

So I have swift code that creates a list of profiles and allows individuals to filter and sort them as well as click on them. Like an address book. It is set up in a Master/Detail format with the master being the list of people and the detail being the individual. I also have a show segue from master which opens up a separate filter and sort page.

My issue is this: when returning from the filter page numberOfRowsInSection is called but not cellForRowAtIndexPath. I have put breakpoints at cellForRowAtIndexPath and they hit when I open the app but not when I return from the filter screen. Thus, the filter narrows down to the appropriate number of rows, and even the links are correct (if I click on the first filtered row the detail view has the correct profile) but because it is not "refreshing" the content of the master's list with cellForRowAtIndexPath when I return from the filter screen the cells in master do not display correctly.

For example, I have the list:
Adam
Andrew
Alex

I click the filter button, get taken to a new screen, do a text based filter for "Andrew" and return to the master list. It shows
Adam

Filtering to the right number of people but still showing the first element from the last list and not refreshing.

Any tips on what I am doing wrong? I can show whatever you want to see of my actual code for numberOfRowsInSection or cellForRowAtIndexPath but not sure how that would be helpful given that the issue is that the latter func is just not being called. Can I force it to fire somehow or is that a hack and is there a structural issue here?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you trigger a `tableView.reloadData()`? Or how do try to refresh the table view?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit tired, lazy and since there is no clear "TL;DR" I'll just ask: have you reloaded the table with `tableView.reloadData()`?

Comment: Do not force to call any delegate methods by yourself. Its a hack. As per my understanding your array is not refreshing. Is that so? When you do filter is the array you are getting with proper data?

Comment: Thank you all for your insights and sorry for the vague post without code. I did try a reloadData but was struggling with where to put it. Ultimately I used a NSNotificationCenter call to trigger it as I left the filter page and it seems to be working now. Sorry for the vague question. I'm a total noob at this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

After filtering the table you have to call: 
`tableView.reloadData()`
this method triggers cellForRowAtIndexPath for the cells